# PCIe error in dmesg log

Tags: drivers, dmesg

I checked the dmesg logs today, and I found this:

```
[108957.958768] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=0018 [108957.958797] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0018(Receiver ID)
[108957.958802] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:   device [8086:2f08] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
[108957.958805] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:    [ 6] Bad TLP               
[108957.958808] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:   Error of this Agent(0018) is reported first
[108957.958813] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0300(Transmitter ID)
[108957.958816] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:   device [10b5:8747] error status/mask=00001000/0000e000
[108957.958819] pcieport 0000:03:00.0:    [12] Replay Timer Timeout  
[108972.972364] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=0018 [108972.972393] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0018(Receiver ID)
[108972.972398] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:   device [8086:2f08] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
[108972.972402] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:    [ 6] Bad TLP               
[109030.841552] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=0018 [109030.841581] pcieport 0000:00:03.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0018(Receiver ID)
[109030.841587] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:   device [8086:2f08] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
[109030.841591] pcieport 0000:00:03.0:    [ 6] Bad TLP
```

Pretty strange, I assume it is due to some third party drivers  ? (Probably nvidia ? I'm currently using 3x nvidia Titan X and 1x Tesla K40c).

Comment: Do not worry if everything works OK. It is only a warning.

Comment: @Pilot6, although it's a warning, I just want to know the reason behind it. Since the machine is used for biological data processing(mainly on GPUs), it is essential that nothing goes wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem with a 980Ti. If you find/have found a solution please post your fix. Thanks

Comment: This will cause performance issues. What do you have in PCIe slot 3? Also, if your motherboard shares PCIe slot 3 with another connector such as an M.2 slot (for an NVMe storage device), what is plugged in there? This is probably not a driver issue. It's hardware or firmware. I am seeing it with an Asus X99 Deluxe II and a Samsung 950 Pro in the M.2 slot (which is connected to PCIe 3). I get the exact same error. I do not have a fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

Solved CONCLUSION: so only needed to use dmesg command to track down which device then change out the keyboard hardware while concurrently changing which USB plug I plugged into was the HARDWARE DEBUG SOLUTION, so far anyhow !!

ISSUE: Machine randomly freezing up - Summary SOLN: The keyboard was defective , swapped it out

-- First REBOOTED , BELOW are the NEXT debug steps

WARNING AT BOOT : USB overpowered rebooting in 15 seconds
Never seen the message ^Above so consistent with Hardware failure / circuit short circuiting issue debugged below !

Find the ERROR via

**dmesg | tail -n30**

**DPC containment event

[ 6] Bad TLP**

**dmesg | grep -i "Bad TLP"**

**dmesg | grep -i "[ 6]"**

So I swapped out GAMER Keyboard ( on port [ 6] ) for >> SINO WEALTH - usb 5-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd << ALSO changed WHICH USB plug
See new device PNP registered per >>

**dmesg | tail -n30**

[ 2020 939537] usb 5-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2021 124622] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=258a, idProduct=0001
[ 2021 124624] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2021 124626] usb 5-1: Product: USB KEYBOARD
[ 2021 124627] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: SINO WEALTH

An easy way to get and NOTE the Timestamp of NEWEST LAST "DPC containment event" message

**dmesg | grep -i "DPC containment event"**

[ 3451 609137]    DPC containment event

**CONFIRMED SOLN PER below**

**dmesg | grep -i "Bad TLP"**

^^ ONLY OLD Timestamp "Bad TLP" messages from OLD defective keyboard hardware i e  newer than "[ 3451 " above

**dmesg | grep -i error**

^^ ONLY OLD Timestamp "error" messages from OLD defective keyboard hardware i e  newer than "[ 3451 "
-AND-

**dmesg | grep -i watchdog**

[    0 162943] NMI watchdog: Enabled  Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter
^^ ONLY One(1) "watchdog" message, which is AOK

-AND-

**dmesg | grep -i IOMMU**

[    0 953589] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[    0 953709] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[    0 955110] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:01 0 to group 0
[    0 955773] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:01 1 to group 1
^^ "IOMMU" messages are ONLY the correct setup messages immediately after a reboot per Timestamp on messages , which is AOK

Solved CONCLUSION: so only needed to use dmesg command to track down which device then change out the keyboard hardware while concurrently changing which USB plug I plugged into was the HARDWARE DEBUG SOLUTION, so far anyhow !!

Intermittent hardware failures and freezing up makes me crazy !

So,

**HTH**